# Async Functions - Firebase, Document Event Listener

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, firebase-authentication

I'm consistently getting the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. I've tried moving around where the `async` is and I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
    document.addEventListener('click', async () => async function(e){
        if(e.target && e.target.id == 'update-order'){
            updateCart();
        }
    }, false);
    
    async function updateCart(){
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
            let username = getUsername(firebaseUser);
            var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
            var foods = document.getElementsByClassName("food-name-id");
            for(let i = 0; i < foods.length; i++){
                let foodData = await queryDB('USERS/' + username + '/CART', 'NAME', foods[i].innerHTML);
                let foodKey = await queryDBKey('USERS/' + username + '/CART', 'NAME', foods[i].innerHTML);

                var postData = {
                    NAME: foodData.NAME,
                    QUANTITY: document.getElementById("quantity-" + foodKey).value,
                    CATEGORY: foodData.CATEGORY,
                    PRICE: foodData.PRICE,
                  };
                var newItemRef = databaseRef.child(username + "/CART/"+ foodKey);
                newItemRef.update(postData);
            }  
            

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `await` inside a callback function that you passed to `onAuthStateChanged()`, so you will have to declare that `async` if you want to use `await` inside it.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (firebaseUser) => {
```

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks!